# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]. in StreamBuffer.php line 278

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

My email cannot send and i get error like Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Network is unreachable #101]. i try to follow step in stackoverflow but nothing happen. 
This my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

This is my mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
```

this my StreamBuffer.php line 278

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create($options);
    $this->_stream = @stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->_params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
    if (false === $this->_stream) {
        throw new Swift_TransportException(
            'Connection could not be established with host '.$this->_params['host'].
            ' ['.$errstr.' #'.$errno.']'
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add mail username and password in your .env

```
  MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
  MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
  MAIL_PORT=2525
  MAIL_USERNAME=username
  MAIL_PASSWORD=password
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Did you add your credentials here.

Comment: Please follow these steps  https://medium.com/@agavitalis/how-to-send-an-email-in-laravel-using-gmail-smtp-server-53d962f01a0c

Comment: still error Connection could not be established with host smtp.googlegmail.com [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known #0]

Comment: Sometimes you will have to run:       php artisan cache:clear and in the rare moments as I have found also running php artisan key:generate

Comment: in my localhost is run but in my server/hosting is get error